# Print ten item in a line......and deal with commas

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that print 10 items at a time from an array, with commas after, except the last item in the line.

I'm able to make it go to a new line at 10 with no comma by using if statements, but when there are less than 10 items in the last line it will still print a comma.

Can anyone gimme a hint on solving this?

Current not working code:

```
 if (count < size-1){
      printf("%d%s", sequence[i],", ");
      count++;
 }
 else if (count == size-1){
      printf("%d%s", sequence[i],"\n");
      count = 1;
```

**example:**
Need this:

```
a, b, c, d, g, j, o, p, q, q, j

k, j, f, a, q
```

Currently getting this:

```
a, b, c, d, g, j, o, p, q, q, j

k, j, f, a, q,   <--- this last comma should not be here
```

Comment: Check whether the index is equal to the array size minus one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you currently have that isn't working for you. You can then ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: @Ken, I think posting code is frowned upon here.

Comment: @Dalek: Um, no. It's actually usually *required* here. Are you not familiar with this site? You should visit the [help] and spend time taking the [tour]. This site almost always *insists* that you supply the code you've written. In fact, there's a specific mention of this in the [help/on-topic] page (see the numbered list of things *not* to ask): *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Another approach:  Set a separator string to `""`.  Now in a loop, `printf("%s%d", separator, sequence[i]);`.  Inside the loop, after printing, set the separator to `", "`.  After everything, print a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current logic is "print a comma if the index is less than 9."  Your logic *should* be "print a comma if the index is less than 9, *and* the index is not the last element in the array"

Working code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInSequence && i < numberOfItemsToPrint; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i < numberOfItemsInSequence - 1 && i < numberOfItemsToPrint - 1) {
        printf(",");
    } else {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have an `if` statement to check whether or not you are printing the 10th element, which determines whether or not you should print a comma.  That `if` statement has a condition, which is currently something along the lines of "index is less than 9."  You should add another condition there, using the "and" operator, spelled as `&&`, which checks that the item currently be printed is not the last item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int sequence[] = {
        'a','b','c','d','g','j','o','p','q','q',
        'j','k','j','f','a','q'
    };
    int wrap_size = 10;
    int i, count=0;
    for(i=0; i< sizeof(sequence)/sizeof(*sequence); ++i){
        if(count++)
            printf(", ");
        printf("%c", sequence[i]);
        if(count == wrap_size){
            putchar('\n');
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if(count)
        putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```